# Clearing the Kivy canvas with a keyboard key press

Tags: python, button, canvas, keyboard, kivy

I am using the Python library [Kivy](https://kivy.org/) to build a simple drawing app.

I want users to be able to draw onto a canvas and then clear the canvas to start a new drawing. I have been able to implement a clear canvas function which is called by a Kivy button when pressed, but I have not been to get the same behaviour when a keyboard key is pressed and calls the same function.

My program contains three files:

- `clear_debugging.py` (the main program)
- `main.kv` (the Kivy file for creating the screens and UI elements)
- `kivy_variables.py` (which I use to store the drawing data in terms of their x,y coordinates)

The code for `clear_debugging.py` is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Line

import kivy_variables

Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

class Painter(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print("INFO: Touch begun!", touch.spos)
        kivy_variables.touch_data.append(touch.spos)
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), group='touch_lines')

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print(touch.spos)
        kivy_variables.touch_data.append(touch.spos)
        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("INFO: Touch released!")

class MainScreen(Screen):

    def exit_app(self):
        print("INFO: Exiting program.")
        Builder.unload_file("main.kv")
        App.get_running_app().stop()
        Window.close()

class DrawScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print('INFO: The key', keycode, 'has been pressed')
        if keycode[1] == 'c':
            self.on_release_clear()
        return True # return True to accept the key

    def on_release_clear(self):
        kivy_variables.touch_data = []
        self.ids.painter.canvas.clear()
        print("INFO: Data cleared.")

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

The code for `main.kv` is:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    DrawScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        cols: 1
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = "draw"
            text: "Draw"
            font_size: 50
            size_hint: 0.15,0.1
        Button:
            on_release: root.exit_app()
            text: "Exit"
            font_size: 50
            size_hint: 0.15,0.1

<DrawScreen>:
    name: "draw"
    BoxLayout:
        Painter
            id: painter
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                color: 0,1,0,1
                background_color: 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
                font_size: 20
                on_press: app.root.current = "main"
                text: "Back"
                size_hint: 0.2,0.1
                pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
            Button:
                color: 0,1,0,1
                background_color: 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
                font_size: 20
                on_press: root.on_release_clear()
                text: "Clear"
                size_hint: 0.2,0.1
                pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
```

The code for `kivy_variables.py` is:

```
touch_data = []
```

When I run `clear_debugging.py` I can click the *Draw* button and then use my mouse to draw on the canvas. I can then clear the canvas by clicking the *Clear* button. But pressing the *c* key (assigned in the `_on_keyboard_down` function of the `DrawScreen` class), the canvas is not cleared. Yet, pressing the *c* key still assigns the `kivy_variables.touch_data` variable to an empty list, `= []`, and it prints the *cleared data* message.

Why is the `self.ids.painter.canvas.clear()` function not being called properly when I use the key press but is behaving as expected when I use the Kivy button? I find I get the same behaviour even if I move the  `self.ids.painter.canvas.clear()` function call into the `_on_keyboard_down` function so that it called directly and not via `on_release_clear`.

Is it something to do with my initialisation procedures or how I am handling keyboard events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is instantiating two different DrawScreens, one when you run `presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")` and the other when the kv file is loaded automatically by the App class. The first one is the one you actually display in the app, but its keyboard is unbound when the second one is instantiated. When you press a key, you see the messages as if it is received correctly, but these messages actually come from the second DrawScreen that isn't drawn anywhere.

You can resolve this by removing the `presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")` and `return presentation` in the build method; if you don't return anything from the build method, the root widget from the kv file is used automatically as the app's root widget. Alternatively, you could rename the kv file.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! And for any future users referring to this thread, the documentation referencing this behaviour of App can be found [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv), where it provides the following example and explanation:

`class ShowcaseApp(App):
    pass`

This method will search for a file named showcase.kv in the directory that contains main.py. The name of the kv file has to be the lowercase name of the class, without the ‘App’ postfix at the end if it exists.